# SimpleInjector: register collection through adapter

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

With SimpleInjector you can register a collection of types:

```cs
interface ILogger { }
class FileLogger : ILogger { }
class SqlLogger : ILogger { }

// usage
var container = new Container();
container.Collection.Register<ILogger>(typeof(FileLogger), typeof(SqlLogger));
container.GetAllInstances<ILogger>(); // returns both ILoggers
```

With that in place, I want to wrap such `ILogger`s with an abstraction `MyLogger` that I can use throughout my application:

```cs
interface MyLogger {
}

class LoggerAdapter : MyLogger {
    public LoggerAdapter(ILogger logger) { }
}
```

However I can't get the container to register the logger adapter as a collection over the registered collection of `ILogger`s:

```cs
var container = new Container();
container.Collection.Register<ILogger>(typeof(FileLogger), typeof(SqlLogger));
container.Collection.Register<MyLogger>(typeof(ILogger));
// ArgumentException: The supplied type ILogger does not inherit from MyLogger.
// Parameter name: serviceTypes
```

While the exception message is clear (`ILogger` doesn't inherit from `LoggerAdapter`), I feel SimpleInjector should be able to make `LoggerAdapter`s from `ILogger`s, by just injecting those `ILogger`s into `LoggerAdapter`s.

Is there a clean way to register a collection of such adapters?

Comment: If you'll just `Register<LoggerAdapter>()` then try to `GetInstance<LoggerAdapter>()`, you'll get your desired adapter with its `ILogger` in place. The only problem is that you're registering multiple implementation of `ILogger` and the container has no way to know which one you want to inject into your `LoggerAdapter`.

Comment: Yeah so what I'm trying to get from the container is a collection of `LoggerAdapter` instances, for the collection of `ILogger`s that I have registered. So in the example I would get two instances, `LoggerAdapter(FileLogger)` and `LoggerAdapter(SqlLogger)`.

Comment: Can't you just register a factory which takes a collection of `ILogger` and returns a collection of adapted `ILogger` ?

Comment: The container does not have a registration for `ILogger`, only for IEnumerable<ILogger>, it will therefore not know which `ILogger` to inject into `LoggerAdapter`. Can you share some light on why you want this.

Comment: `LoggerAdapter` implements an interface (e.g. `MyLogger`) defined by the consumer. The consumer is only interested in the collection of `MyLogger`. So what I want is to decouple the registrations of `ILogger` from `MyLogger`.

Comment: Please show the full `LoggerAdapter` as the current supplied code doesn't implement `ILogger`

Comment: @bouke what does the constructor look like?

Comment: `LoggerAdapter` does not implement `ILogger`, but another interface (e.g. `MyLogger`). I want to decouple `ILogger` from `MyLogger`, through `LoggerAdapter` (composite).

Comment: The constructor of `LoggerAdapter` takes an `ILogger`: `LoggerAdapter(ILogger logger)`.

Comment: As @Ric.Net has already said, you haven't registered a single instance of `ILogger`, you've registered a collection. Which one are you expecting to be injected?

Comment: That's the thing; I want to register a collection of `LoggerAdapter`, based on the registered collection of `ILogger`.

Comment: Then change the constructor to accept a collection: `LoggerAdapter(IEnumerable<ILogger> loggers) { }`

Comment: I misunderstood. You want an `LoggerAdapter` for each `ILogger`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions here. The first thing that comes to my mind is to change your adapter to accept a list of loggers instead:

```cs
class LoggerAdapter : MyLogger
{
    public LoggerAdapter(IEnumerable<ILogger> loggers) { }
}
```

This is likely a more pleasant solution as this allows you to inject a single `MyLogger` into your consumers, instead having to inject a collection of `MyLogger` instances.

If you really need a list of `MyLogger` instances, you can register the collection manually as follows:

```cs
container.RegisterSingleton<IEnumerable<MyLogger>>(
    () => container.GetAllInstances<ILogger>()
        .Select(logger => new LoggerAdapter(logger)));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and SimpleInjector, working with it has been much fun. The answer would indeed work for the example I posted. However in my actual code, the types `ILogger`, `LoggerAdapter` and `MyLogger` are generic over the same type `T`. The first alternative you posted would still work and is what I'm using now. However to please semantics, I would like to use the second alternative, but I'm failing to see how that can be done over a generic. For one; `typeof(IEnumerable<MyLogger<>>)` would not be valid code.

Comment: @bouke: the second solution is not feasible when your types are generic. I can cook up some other solutions, but tbh, I think you should go with the first, as that class already acts as an adapter.

Comment: the class is indeed an adapter, but I would like to preserve semantics in the consumer of that adapter; it should be aware of the "many consumers" (adapters). I'm interested to see what that would look like.